# nvd3 plot with too many points fails - Cannot read property 'x' of null

Tags: nvd3.js

I have a line chart with nvd3.
It works fine when I have fewer points, but I get a javascript error when I have more point:

```
Cannot read property 'x' of null
```

Here is the full html for the case with more data which fails:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            
        <div id="coverage"><svg style="width:1200px;height:400px;"></svg></div>
        <script>
                coverage=[{"values": [{"y": 0.1, "x": 0}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 1}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 2}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 3}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 4}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 5}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 6}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 7}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 8}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 9}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 10}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 11}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 12}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 13}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 14}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 15}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 16}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 17}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 18}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 19}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 20}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 21}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 22}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 23}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 24}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 25}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 26}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 27}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 28}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 29}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 30}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 31}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 32}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 33}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 34}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 35}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 36}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 37}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 38}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 39}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 40}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 41}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 42}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 43}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 44}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 45}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 46}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 47}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 48}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 49}], "key": "qq003.1.3", "yAxis": "1"}, {"values": [{"y": 0.1, "x": 0}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 1}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 2}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 3}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 4}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 5}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 6}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 7}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 8}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 9}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 10}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 11}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 12}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 13}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 14}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 15}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 16}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 17}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 18}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 19}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 20}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 21}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 22}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 23}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 24}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 25}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 26}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 27}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 28}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 29}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 30}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 31}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 32}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 33}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 34}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 35}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 36}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 37}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 38}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 39}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 40}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 41}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 42}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 43}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 44}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 45}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 46}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 47}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 48}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 49}], "key": "qq003.1.67", "yAxis": "1"}, {"values": [{"y": 247677.0, "x": 0}, {"y": 250012.0, "x": 1}, {"y": 287416.0, "x": 2}, {"y": 327385.0, "x": 3}, {"y": 276739.0, "x": 4}, {"y": 247264.0, "x": 5}, {"y": 234246.0, "x": 6}, {"y": 252476.0, "x": 7}, {"y": 263584.0, "x": 8}, {"y": 244878.0, "x": 9}, {"y": 263238.0, "x": 10}, {"y": 223955.0, "x": 11}, {"y": 147838.0, "x": 12}, {"y": 216088.0, "x": 13}, {"y": 219334.0, "x": 14}, {"y": 464921.0, "x": 15}, {"y": 253147.0, "x": 16}, {"y": 143214.0, "x": 17}, {"y": 263756.0, "x": 18}, {"y": 289643.0, "x": 19}, {"y": 219631.0, "x": 20}, {"y": 280396.0, "x": 21}, {"y": 228272.0, "x": 22}, {"y": 205129.0, "x": 23}, {"y": 277684.0, "x": 24}, {"y": 336930.0, "x": 25}, {"y": 206536.0, "x": 26}, {"y": 184942.0, "x": 27}, {"y": 288391.0, "x": 28}, {"y": 265598.0, "x": 29}, {"y": 214029.0, "x": 30}, {"y": 205708.0, "x": 31}, {"y": 238413.0, "x": 32}, {"y": 173776.0, "x": 33}, {"y": 231737.0, "x": 34}, {"y": 189285.0, "x": 35}, {"y": 299765.0, "x": 36}, {"y": 254324.0, "x": 37}, {"y": 231075.0, "x": 38}, {"y": 425653.0, "x": 39}, {"y": 344885.0, "x": 40}, {"y": 394357.0, "x": 41}, {"y": 184156.0, "x": 42}, {"y": 251984.0, "x": 43}, {"y": 236977.0, "x": 44}, {"y": 280948.0, "x": 45}, {"y": 305699.0, "x": 46}, {"y": 249000.0, "x": 47}, {"y": 281287.0, "x": 48}, {"y": 247748.0, "x": 49}], "key": "qq001.2.047", "yAxis": "1"}];
    
    
            nv.addGraph(function() {
            var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
    
            chart.margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 100, left: 60});
    
            var datum = coverage;
                    chart.xAxis
                    .rotateLabels(-25).tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
                chart.yAxis
                    .axisLabel('Coverage').tickFormat(d3.format(',.02f'));
    
              chart.showLegend(true);
                d3.select('#coverage svg')
                .datum(datum)
                .transition().duration(500)
                .attr('width', 1200)
                .attr('height', 400)
                .call(chart);
            });
    
        </script>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you have identical points in the three series. Refer to https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/873

Try using useVoronoi(false);

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            
        <div id="coverage"><svg style="width:1200px;height:400px;"></svg></div>
        <script>
                coverage=[{"values": [{"y": 0.2, "x": 0}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 1}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 2}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 3}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 4}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 5}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 6}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 7}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 8}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 9}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 10}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 11}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 12}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 13}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 14}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 15}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 16}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 17}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 18}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 19}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 20}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 21}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 22}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 23}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 24}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 25}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 26}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 27}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 28}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 29}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 30}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 31}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 32}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 33}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 34}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 35}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 36}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 37}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 38}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 39}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 40}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 41}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 42}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 43}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 44}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 45}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 46}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 47}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 48}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 49}], "key": "qq003.1.3", "yAxis": "1"}, {"values": [{"y": 0.1, "x": 0}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 1}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 2}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 3}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 4}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 5}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 6}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 7}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 8}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 9}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 10}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 11}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 12}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 13}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 14}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 15}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 16}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 17}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 18}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 19}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 20}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 21}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 22}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 23}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 24}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 25}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 26}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 27}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 28}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 29}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 30}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 31}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 32}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 33}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 34}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 35}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 36}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 37}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 38}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 39}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 40}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 41}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 42}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 43}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 44}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 45}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 46}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 47}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 48}, {"y": 0.1, "x": 49}], "key": "qq003.1.67", "yAxis": "1"}, {"values": [{"y": 247677.0, "x": 0}, {"y": 250012.0, "x": 1}, {"y": 287416.0, "x": 2}, {"y": 327385.0, "x": 3}, {"y": 276739.0, "x": 4}, {"y": 247264.0, "x": 5}, {"y": 234246.0, "x": 6}, {"y": 252476.0, "x": 7}, {"y": 263584.0, "x": 8}, {"y": 244878.0, "x": 9}, {"y": 263238.0, "x": 10}, {"y": 223955.0, "x": 11}, {"y": 147838.0, "x": 12}, {"y": 216088.0, "x": 13}, {"y": 219334.0, "x": 14}, {"y": 464921.0, "x": 15}, {"y": 253147.0, "x": 16}, {"y": 143214.0, "x": 17}, {"y": 263756.0, "x": 18}, {"y": 289643.0, "x": 19}, {"y": 219631.0, "x": 20}, {"y": 280396.0, "x": 21}, {"y": 228272.0, "x": 22}, {"y": 205129.0, "x": 23}, {"y": 277684.0, "x": 24}, {"y": 336930.0, "x": 25}, {"y": 206536.0, "x": 26}, {"y": 184942.0, "x": 27}, {"y": 288391.0, "x": 28}, {"y": 265598.0, "x": 29}, {"y": 214029.0, "x": 30}, {"y": 205708.0, "x": 31}, {"y": 238413.0, "x": 32}, {"y": 173776.0, "x": 33}, {"y": 231737.0, "x": 34}, {"y": 189285.0, "x": 35}, {"y": 299765.0, "x": 36}, {"y": 254324.0, "x": 37}, {"y": 231075.0, "x": 38}, {"y": 425653.0, "x": 39}, {"y": 344885.0, "x": 40}, {"y": 394357.0, "x": 41}, {"y": 184156.0, "x": 42}, {"y": 251984.0, "x": 43}, {"y": 236977.0, "x": 44}, {"y": 280948.0, "x": 45}, {"y": 305699.0, "x": 46}, {"y": 249000.0, "x": 47}, {"y": 281287.0, "x": 48}, {"y": 247748.0, "x": 49}], "key": "qq001.2.047", "yAxis": "1"}];
    
    
            nv.addGraph(function() {
            var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
    
            chart.margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 100, left: 60});
    
            var datum = coverage;
                    chart.xAxis
                    .rotateLabels(-25).tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
                chart.yAxis
                    .axisLabel('Coverage').tickFormat(d3.format(',.02f'));
    
              chart.showLegend(true).useVoronoi(false);
                d3.select('#coverage svg')
                .datum(datum)
                .transition().duration(500)
                .attr('width', 1200)
                .attr('height', 400)
                .call(chart);
            });
    
        </script>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Great. That fixed it. Also noticed that upgrading to version 1.8 of nvd3 would fix it as well...